# why bloom filters do not work, tell me please

Tags: indexing, hive, orc, bloom-filter

I have two tables: original and new with bloom filters. Bloom filter created for int column ( CLUSTERED BY and 'orc.bloom.filter.columns'). in hdfs in the partition, I see the number of files = the number of unique values ​​in the column.  but when I query ( select min(...) from table where id = ...) these tables, requests finishes execution in the same time. and in job's logs and in 'explain analyze' I do not see the use of a bloom filter and the request reads the entire partition. what else needs to be configured in order for the bloom filter to work, requests are executed faster, and not all files in the partition are read, but only one file with the desired id?

Answer (score 2):

Bloom filters can help not in all cases.

ORC contains indexes on file level, stripe level and row level (for 10000 rows, configurable). **If PPD configured**, indexes (min, max values) can be used to skip reading files (**footer part will be read anyway**), stripes also can be skipped. **These indexes are useful for filtering sortable sequential values and range queries.** like integer number for example.  **For indexes to be efficient you should sort data** by index keys when inserting. Unsorted index is not efficient because all stripes can contain all keys.

Sorting during insert can be expensive.

Having only Indexes is enough in most cases.

Bloom filters are structures which can help to check if key is not present in the dataset with 100 percent probability.

**Bloom filters efficient for equality queries, especially for not sequential unsorted values** like GUIDs. MIN/MAX indexes do not work efficiently for such values. Filter by specific GUID should be very efficient with Bloom filter.

For sortable sequential values like integer id, min/max values stored in ORC indexes (sorted) are better.